# bs4 find contents of tag if class="post-likes"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some text that looks like this:

```
<meta content="http://schema.org/LikeAction" itemprop="interactionType">
<meta content="10" itemprop="userInteractionCount"/>
<span class="post-likes">10 Likes</span>
</meta></div>
<div itemprop="interactionStatistic" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/InteractionCounter">
```

I want to find the contents of all `<span>` tags where `class="post-likes"`, such as the 3rd line in the text above. There are many many span tags in the full file I'm parsing, so I only want to look at the ones that have the `class="post-likes"`. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done this way:

```
your_spans = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "post-likes"})
```